# docker compose more than 1 container on same folder

Tags: docker, directory, docker-compose, volumes

I need to create somes containers :
 1 data container.
 2 applicatives containers. They must have access to the same folder (in data container).

My problem is : 
 When I create the 2 applicatives containers 2 results :

- All container have an instance of this container (so no sharing)
- One of the 2 container take the control of the shared folder, and the second fail.

In images of the 2 applicative container I have :

- Container A : somes files in shared folder.
- Container B : an application which use this folder.

I tried something like that (and many alternative) :

```
containerA:
 image: AAA
 volumes:
  - /var/shared
  - /opt/A
 volumes_from:
  - dataContainer
containerB:
 image: BBB
 volumes:
 - /var/shared
 - /opt/B
 volumes_from:
  - dataContainer
dataContainer:
 image: CCC
 volumes:
  - /var/shared
  - /var/A
  - /var/B
```

In this case container A and B cant see thier folder.

1 applicative container alone with dataContainer works. But 2 applicative container in same time never works..

Any idea ?

Thks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `volumes:` lines in the `containerA` and `containerB` services are messing with the volumes, you should remove them. You only need `volumes_from` in those services.

Also make sure to `docker-compose rm` after trying any change. docker-compose [preserves volumes between restarts](http://docs.docker.com/compose/#preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created) so you could be getting an old cached volume instead.